# MySQL sorting rows by record groups

Tags: mysql

I want to sort rows in table by colomn "value", where Field = "order", grouping rows by ObjectId:

```
 Id | ObjectId | Field | Value
------------------------------
 1  |    1     | size  |  big
 2  |    1     | order |   2   //unsorted
 3  |    2     | size  | small
 4  |    2     | order |   1   //unsorted
 5  |    3     | size  | medium
 6  |    3     | order |   3   //unsorted
```

Expected result:

```
 Id | ObjectId | Field | Value
------------------------------
 3  |    2     | size  | small
 4  |    2     | order |   1   //sorted
 1  |    1     | size  |  big
 2  |    1     | order |   2   //sorted
 5  |    3     | size  | medium
 6  |    3     | order |   3   //sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join in the field value for size first:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.object_id, max(case when field = 'order' then value end) as ordering
      from t
      group by t.object_id
     ) tsum
     on t.object_id = tsum.object_id
order by tsum.ordering, t.object_id, id;
```

This assigns the same "ordering" to everything with the same `object_id`.